# I need help finding the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find a $3×3$ symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 3$, $\lambda_2 = 6$ and eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 3$ generated by $v=(1,-1,1)$. I don't know how to proceed

Comment: @D I think he means the eigenspace associated with $\lambda=3$, which is to say that the matrix has Eigenvalues 1 3 and 6.

Comment: yes, i mean this sorry

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagonal matrix $A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr 0&6&0\cr 0&0&3}$ and
$P=\pmatrix{0&0&1\cr 0&1&-1\cr 1&-1&1}$ consider $PAP^{-1}$

$P$ defines a basis change between the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $(a,b,e_1-e_2+e_3)$ and is symmetric.

Comment: I know only 2 eigenvalue